# How do I create a pretty link to a Telegram group?

Tags: telegram

I know how to create a pretty link to a channel (t.me/mychannel).

I know how to create an invite link to a (super)group. However, I can't seem to control how the link looks like.

Is there a way to create a pretty link to a supergroup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not possible on the web version :(

On the mobile and desktop version it's located under `Group Info` from (`Group Settings` / `Manage Group`), and this section doesn't exist on [webogram](https://github.com/zhukov/webogram) yet.

Unfortunately the web version of Telegram lags behind the other platform versions.

Comment: Thanks, I actually looked for it on mobile and didn't find it at first.

Comment: actually it is under group info / Edit / Group Type